# Codefolding / Indent guides in Vim?

Tags: vim, highlight

During a research for useful vim plugins I found a screenshot of a vim window showing some kind of dotted guides highlighting either indentation or folds. I'm not sure about what they highlight actually.

Does anyone know which plugin generates these guides and what their purpose is?

You can find the screenshot right here: http://oi54.tinypic.com/2yysefm.jpg

Answer (score 6):

If you use tabs to indent your code, you can use the `'list'` option to make your tabs visible.

In your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:┊\ <-- don't forget the trailing space.
```

Obviously, this will work only if Vim supports utf-8.

Comment: Good hint! Although I normally do use spaces instead of tabs. I have this in my config: `set list
set listchars=tab:»-,trail:·,eol:¶,extends:>,precedes:<`